# matplotlib scatter works in ipython notebook, but not console

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to learn to use matplotlib and am following a tutorial to draw a scatterplot where I specify the size of the points. (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2 # 0 to 15 point radiuses

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I am running ipython on Mac OS X using the command `ipython --pylab` and get the following error.

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1048         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1049         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1050             func(*args)
   1051 
   1052         renderer.close_group('figure')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2074 
   2075         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2076             a.draw(renderer)
   2077 
   2078         renderer.close_group('axes')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/collections.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    733     def draw(self, renderer):
    734         self.set_sizes(self._sizes, self.figure.dpi)
--> 735         Collection.draw(self, renderer)
    736 
    737 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     58         before(artist, renderer)
---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60         after(artist, renderer)
     61 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/collections.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    305                     self._linewidths, self._linestyles,
    306                     self._antialiaseds, self._urls,
--> 307                     self._offset_position)
    308 
    309         gc.restore()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.pyc in draw_path_collection(self, gc, master_transform, paths, all_transforms, offsets, offsetTrans, facecolors, edgecolors, linewidths, linestyles, antialiaseds, urls, offset_position)
     77             path_ids.append((path, transform))
     78         master_transform = master_transform.get_matrix()
---> 79         all_transforms = [t.get_matrix() for t in all_transforms]
     80         offsetTrans = offsetTrans.get_matrix()
     81         gc.draw_path_collection(master_transform, path_ids, all_transforms,

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_matrix'
```

However, if I run the same code in an ipython notebook started using the command `ipython notebook --pylab=inline`, it works fine.

How can I make this work from the console?

additional info:

- I'm running the same version of numpy on both the console and ipython
  notebook: numpy.**version** = '1.9.0.dev-7457f15'
- The os is OSX 10.8.5
- If I run using `ipython` instead of `ipython --pylab`, I get the same
  error.
- Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 13 2013, 13:05:22)
- IPython 2.0.0-dev

Thanks

Comment: Check the version of numpy (`numpy.__version__`) you see in both interpreters are the same. Give the verison of all the software you use in general. Os X (and Maverick even more) do weird things with Python and especially numpy. Try with Stable Matplotlib also. Add you version of Os X (10.8 Montain Lion) even if here you can guess it from traceback, not everybody will took the pain to search. Finally we try to push people not to use `--pylab` it has undesirable side effect. on IPython 1.0 and above it is better to use explicit import and `%matplotlib inline` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I tried using `ipython` instead of `ipython --pylab`, but got the same error. I also tried using `python`, again with the same error.

Comment: (detail but for dev version you might want to give the exact commit `import IPython: print IPython.sys_info()`. You are also on numpy dev, try numpy stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a `backend` problem on the `matplotlib` side. Look at the last section of error message. It indicates that something is not right in the `macosx` `backend`, which is used as the interactive backend in `OSX` environment.

The reason that it works under inline mode: `pylab=inline` confirmed this. As in the inline mode, it is not the interactive backend, but one of the non-interactive backends that is doing the work (`inline` backend most likely). So, it works.

The solution is probably what @Matt suggested, switch to a stable version of `matplotlib`

Comment: then we can probably also test `--pylab=qt` or `gtk`to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help, @Matt & @CT Zhu! I didn't realize I wasn't on a stable version. After reinstalling with 
`pip install numpy --upgrade
pip install scipy --upgrade
sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade
sudo pip install ipython --upgrade
sudo pip install pandas --upgrade
sudo pip install sympy --upgrade
sudo pip install nose --upgrade`
everything worked great